# fit mapPanel in tabPanel

Tags: extjs, dictionary, extjs4.1

I use extjs4.1 with geoext2 in my web app.
I want to load mapPanel to tabPanel via ajax and it fill tabPanel height and width.
If i set mapPanel height and width i can see it in tabPanel but it can't fill tabPanel because i set it height and width.Following code:

```
mapPanel = Ext.create("GeoExt.panel.Map", {
            renderTo: "mappanel",
            height: 575,
            width: 1124,
            map:map,
            zoom: 11,
            tbar : toolbar
        });
var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            region: 'center', // a center region is ALWAYS required for border layout
            deferredRender: false,
            activeTab: 0,     // first tab initially active
            items: [{
                title: 'History',
                autoScroll: true
            }, {
                title: 'Center Panel',
                autoScroll: true
            }]
        });
```

I insert MapPanel to tabPanel when user click on grid column that has icon via following code.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columnLines: true,
        columns: [
            {
                menuDisabled: true,
                sortable: false,
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 20,
                items: [{
                    icon   : '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/icons/show.png';?>',
                    tooltip: 'Show Map',
                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        var rec = store.getAt(rowIndex);
                        var jsonData = Ext.encode(store.proxy.reader.jsonData);
                        tabs.remove(tabs.getComponent(2));
                        tabs.insert(2,{
                            title:'Map',
                            layout: 'fit',
                            loader: {
                                scripts: true,
                                autoLoad :true,
                                params:{
                                    history:jsonData,
                                    index:rowIndex
                                },

                                failure : function(){
                                    alert('failed');
                                },
                                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('MapWidget/HistoryMap');?>'

                            }
                        });
                        tabs.setActiveTab(2);
                        tabs.doLayout();
                       }
                }]
            },
...
```

But when i clean height and width in mapPanel options i can't see it in tabPanel!
How can i load mapPanel to tabPanel to fill it's content?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs

> Do not use this option if the Component is to be a child item of a
>   Container. It is the responsibility of the Container's layout manager
>   to render and manage its child items.

Here's some example code for loading components remotely in the correct way: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/component-loader/component-loader.html